# Python- requiring user to input certain text as part of their input

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

I am new to Python and am having trouble with input verification. Specifically, I am asking the user to input a URL but I want to make sure they are inputting either "http" or "https" as part of their URL. This is what I have been doing:

```
user_url = raw_input(please enter your URL: )
while "https" or "http" not in user_url:
    print "you must enter a valid URL format, try again"
    user_url = raw_input(please enter your URL: )
```

When I use this code, any text is still accepted, even if it does not contain "http" or "https". Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have to explicitly spell out each condition: `while "https" not in user_url and "http" not in user_url:`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
while "https" not in user_url and "http" not in user_url:
```

but:

```
while "http" not in user_url:
```

is enough as `http` is included in `https`.

However, the following would be considered as ok: "www.domain.com/http" because it contains http. So you should either use a regex or use the following:

```
while user_url[:4] != "http":
```

Answer (score 0):

As John Gordon said in the comments the proper way to do it is like this :

```
while "https" not in user_url and "http" not in user_url:
```

What you have doesn't work because, as you wrote it, python sees two statements that have to be evaluated to see if they are true or false : 
 1. `"https"` 
 2.`"http" not in user_url`

The truth value of a non-empty string is always `True` (you can check it with `bool("somestring")` ).
Because statement 1 is just a string it means that it is always true, so you end up always running the loop whatever your input may be.

*Some additionnal comments :*

To check a url, you need to see if "http" is at the start of the url because "://google.http.com" is not a valid url, so a better way would be : `while not user_url.startswith("http") and not user_url.startswith("https"):`

Answer (score -1):

You should use:

```
user_url = raw_input("please enter your URL: ")
while user_url.find("http") != -1:
    print "you must enter a valid URL format, try again"
    user_url = raw_input("please enter your URL: ")
```

Comment: forgot a large part of the question last time. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score -2):

```
while "https" not in user_url and "http" not in user_url:
```